# I seem to be stuck in the bug den?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

I seem to have hit a dead end in *Shadowrun Returns'* bug den.  After the two bugs broke out of the walls, there doesn't seem to be anything else happening.  I'm still in combat mode but waiting multiple turns doesn't open up any more walls.  What am I supposed to do?  I've also scouted the entire map, there are no more enemies that I can find.

Here is a screenshot of the location
[image: bug den screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok mate, did some digging :)

it seems like you have to trigger another bug, bursting out of the wall in the hallway that leads to our "stuck-room".

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [dumpt.com](https://dumpt.com/img/files/fsfjcxdxdi72rsudqk1s.jpg))</sub>

Just put all of your party members straight in front of the wall and end turn, that should trigger it.

Spoiler!!!:

> There is also a bug with the final boss, it seems like you have to attack her the very last! first kill everything she summons and the pillars, and once she resummons them or tries to, she is supposed to run away and trigger a cutscene.
>  OK… the pillar thing is going on endlessly so just do that: Don't attack her at all, clean out the pillars she uses, kill the bugs until none respawn, after no bugs respawn, get one more pillar, and than attack her directly, it worked for me (I did a lot more pillars though) good luck!

I hope this helps.

Comment: fwiw I managed to bypass fighting the queen completely by steamrolling the summoner.  No pillars nothing :P  rifle + full auto = imba